# How to avoid Microsoft Edge to open automatically when network connection is lost

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a very critical problem with a PC with Windows 10 Home that is designed to be unattended all the time.

If, for some reason, the PC loses network connection, Microsoft Edge is opened automatically trying to load a web page belonging to the firewall. In that case, a person must go to the PC and close the browser Window manually.

Is there a way to stop this annoying behaviour?

EDIT:

Microsoft Edge also opens after the PC is rebooted. This is because that PC does not have Internet Access.

The URL that is loaded in the browser is: https://172.16.1.1:4100/fw_user_login.html?redirect=http://www.msftconnecttest.com/redirect

I think the firewall link is loaded because browser tries to connect to msftconnecttest site, and since there is no Internet Connection, URL is redirected to firewall.

The base problem here is that Microsoft Edge is opening.

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: The behavior you describe is not default behavior.  **It does not happen with a default install of Windows.**  So the only explanation for the behavior is an application you have installed on the system is opening up the default browser.  What page is it attempting to open up?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited the question and added also that Edge opens even after reboot because there is no Internet connection present.

Comment: Is the router acting like a captive portal? Wasn't there a setting in Win10 that allows the browser to be automatically opened when a captive portal is detected to facilitate completion of the connection?

Comment: Please try the solution here and let us know if that resolves the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491861/how-to-disable-automatically-browser-opening-on-wi-fi-hotspot-connection-for-win

Comment: @music2myear Thanks!! that solved the problem!!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.